# Call back not working when Link is clicked in react router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I've been trying to send a call back to parent component C from child component A to set state in parent C! This state will be sent to another child component B. I have a link component in A which calls the component in B but the child component needs the state from parent component and when I click on the link in A the call Back is not being called but I want it to be called.

```
Class C extends react.Component
{
    constructor(props: any)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
        somestate: '',
        }
    }
    CallBack(somestate:string)
    {
        this.Setstate({somestate, somestate},()=>{console.log(this.state.somestate);});
    }
    render()
    {
        return( 
            <A CallBack={this.CallBack} />
            <Route path='/somestate' >
            <B somestate={this.state.somestate} />
            </Route>

        )
    }
}
Class A extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props: any)
    {
        super(props);
    }
    callback()
    {
        this.props.CallBack();//causing errror when i click Link tag
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
        <Link to='/somestate'>
            <button onClick={this.callback()}>click me</button>
        </Link>
        )
    }
}
Class B extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props: any)
    {
        super(props);
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
        <div>
            this.props.somestate;
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm not able to call the call back in props. I'm guessing we cant use call back to parent and link at the same time. So how to actually use it.

Comment: you can remove link and add "this.props.history.push('/somestate');" in your callback function

Comment: Also you should [bind your methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-an-event-handler-like-onclick-to-a-component)  or use ES6 arrow function and correct **this.setState**

Answer (score 2):

According to the [React Router documents](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/others) you should pass others props like **onClick** as bellow:

```
<Link to="/somestate" onClick={this.callback} className="some-classname">Click me</Link>
```

Also you can pass className so to shape the link as you want.